# Visual Studio Web Project is not Attaching to IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

A web project that I have is not appearing in my IIS Express directory with the other project in my solution. It was appearing there the last time I loaded visual studio and now it won't load into IIS Express no matter how many things I google and try.

I hit the run button in Visual Studio 2015 which tries to launch the project in Google Chrome which responds with "local host refused connection". When I look at localhost (IIS Express) it only has my other project running inside it.

The only change I made was to add some packages into node_modules which I can guess may make the project incompatible with IIS Express but there is no error at all.

How do I get my web project to launch in IIS Express again?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by restarting my computer. No matter how many times I restarted visual studio it didn't help.

Classic case of turn it on and off again.